# Equivalent spring constant of an nth order system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, spring

I am looking for the spring constant of this below diagram

[image: spring in series, parallal]

**I think the solution will look something like this**

[image]

But I am looking for more like a generalized formula. Any help is appreciated. Also I am not sure if it's a duplicate question. If someone can point me, that is also fine. Thanks

Comment: It's nasty that $k_1$... etc are all different values. It might lend itself to a simpler expression if they were all the same. In what way would you want the expression to be "more generalized"?

Comment: There are simplification formulas for continued fractions that you could look up in mathematical formularies.

Answer (score 2):

Dip773, you wrote the most general solution already.

As stated by Floris, you can obtain a generalized formula ($k_{eff} = k_p\cdot\phi$, where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=1.61803...$ is the golden ratio) if all spring constants are equal ($k_n = k_p$ for each $n$). In order to obtain this, you also need the hypotesis that $n$ is large, and that adding one more spring on the right do not change too much the effective $k_{eff}$ constant (which is actually a very reasonable request).

In your case, it is more involved. Some assumptions may help you to have the feeling of the solution. First, if $k_n \ll k_p$, if the latest status is the parallel of $k_N$ and $k_p$, then $k_{eff}=k_p$; if the latest status is a single spring under the parallel, then $k_{eff}=k_N$.
This leads to the conclusion that the only interesting cases are the one described above (all $k_n=k_p$) or when the $k_p$ and $k_n$ are all quite similar among them, but for this case one can extract some closed formula with additional hypoteses and approximations.